# Blazor/Razor page @model note recognized "The name ''model' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razor-pages

I'm working on a Blazor page which is relatively simple and will pull from a sqlite database that was generated using the Add-Migration command. The tutorial I'm following they have an index.cshtml and thus an index.chtml.cs file where they are making a class IndexModel that inherits from PageModel and then calling that model in the index.cshtml file with the @model IndexModel tag at the top. I'm getting an error that the "The name ''model' does not exist in the current context". I'm relatively new so I apologize if this is something different in my versions of .NET or a difference between Razor and Blazor.

I made the IndexModel class on the same file where my primary class is

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public readonly FlipDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(FlipDbContext context) => _context = context;

    public async void OnGet()
    {
        Flips = await _context.Flips.ToListAsync();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Flip> Flips { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Flip>();

}
```

When I add the @model IndexModel to the top of my Index.razor is when I get the issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think _Blazor_ supports `@model`, that's only a cshtml MVC View feature (which is written is _Razor_, not to be confusing or anything).

Comment: If your tutorial uses cshtml files (which should be located in a "View" folder), then it's not Blazor, it's regular MVC using Razor (which could be MVC or Razor Pages, wow this is complicated now that I say this out loud). If you have `.razor` files in a "Pages" and a "_Host.cshtml" as well, then that's Blazor.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,`Index.razor` is a blazor component,not a razor page,so it doesnt't support `@model`.And Blazor project doesn't contain razor page by default,it only contains blazor components(xxx.razor),you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And since you have the `IndexModel` associated `PageModel`,it means the page is a razor page.And if you want to use razor page,you can create a razor page project,here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).